# including jQuery lib in parent window only

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to access the jQuery lib from an iframe, when it's included in the parent window only? I have a parent window which loads (sometimes hundreds) of iframes. In each iframe I want to execute some jQuery functions. I can only get this working if I define the lib in each iframe, using :

```
<script src="/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

However, I would prefer, for faster loading, that I include the above script tag only in the parent window, then from each child/iframe access the parent's library to execute a function that affects the iframe.

Thanks for the response. Here is what I have in the child frame :

```
&lt;script>
var $ = parent.jQuery;

$(this, document).ready(function(){
    var step = 0.2;
    $('body', document).css('MozTransform','scale(0.2)');
});

&lt;/script>
```

And what I'd expect is that once the child's doc is "ready" it would shrink itself down to 20%. Except its not working. Is it possible, or should I try add the child's code to the parent doc and assign ids to each frame, then loop through them.

Using 
    $( document ).ready(function(){
        $('body').css('MozTransform','scale('

results in the parent window scaling down. I'm wanting to scale down the iframe.

Comment: Your browser should cache the file automatically, so even if you've got a hundred iframes it should be loaded just once from the server.

Comment: hard to fathom in this day and age why you need 100's of Iframes if they are on your domain, use cases for iframes are getting smaller and smaller

Comment: we found a good use for iframes. Sometimes you only have one optyion, that's when you know you're working on some tricky stuff beyond the realm of your avg coder.

Comment: I wonder if you could just use AJAX instead... It'd be helpful if you explained why you're using them. Also, iframes are usually the solution found in the realm _of_ the average coder, not above it

Comment: Sure. We're using iframes because what we're doing is loading up a collection of website pages inside them. Because each page could use different DOCTYPE tags, we need them in frames so that the parent DOC is not affected by different standards and styles. Additionally, we're making use of the new css zoom feature so that a user could zoom in and out, on the actual content, on demand. I think iframes are the best and only solution here. We don't want static thumbnails which would need to be regularly updated, take up valuable space and give the user no idea of what the page really looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `iframe`s are in the same domain as the parent document, you can easily get a reference to the parent window's jQuery:

```
var $ = parent.jQuery;
```

Or if you have `iframe`s nested more than one level deep:

```
var $ = top.jQuery;
```

However, jQuery by default will only query the document from where it was included. In case you need to query the given `iframe`'s DOM, you have two options:

Pass `document`, which in this case points to the given `iframe`'s `window.document`, as [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context):

```
$('#elementInsideIframe', document).doSomething();
```

Or, store a jQuery object containing the `iframe`'s document and `.find()` its descendants.

```
var $dom = $(document);
$dom.find('#elementInsideIframe').doSomething();
```

### Live demo

- [Parent window](http://jsfiddle.net/6zsVr/2/)
- [`iframe` contents](http://jsfiddle.net/cSVZT/2/)

---

Despite what others say, caching is not "good enough" for your use case. jQuery has quite some init overhead and it is something that you do not want to include hundreds of times.

---

As per OP update:

Just use `$(document).ready()` inside the frames. In an (i)frame context, `document` points to the given frame's `window.document`.

Also, if you're using jQuery >= 1.8, you don't need to use vendor prefixes - jQuery will use the appropriate vendor-prefixed property in case the standard one is not supported.

Demo: [parent](http://jsfiddle.net/6zsVr/4/), [iframe](http://jsfiddle.net/cSVZT/4/)

Comment: This is pretty much what I was looking for, and is successfully calling the parent lib. However, the code in the child lib is not executing as expected. Please see edit to my question.

Comment: @user1749141 replace `$(this, document).ready` by `$(document).ready` and it will work. Also, if you're using jQuery >= 1.8, you don't need to put vendor prefixes so `.css('transform', value)` will work too.

Comment: touch. How do I prompt you?

Comment: @user1749141 not sure what you mean with 'prompt'. If the problem is solved, you can mark this answer as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235), and in case you need further help you can ask a new question and link it to me. `=]`

Comment: Hi Fab, not sure how to link it to you. Hence the "touch". I updated my question.

Comment: @user1749141 yes, `$('body')` should be `$('body', document)` or even better: `$(document.body)`. Don't forget the context when passing string selectors. You can also see how I did it in my answer update's iframe code.

Answer (score 0):

The overhead of jerking around with the html-code of a parent window or top window will cost more than the extra line of script to to load jquery as you should.

Load it individually in each frame, possibly use an online version of jquery, this will increase the chanses of the client having the library loaded before entering your site.

In example

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: You may be right with the extra work and headaches involved. May just stick with waht we've got and hope each browser's cache does it's job properly over an SSL connection. Regarding third party scripts, what if there's an overseas cable down between Continent A and Continent B for a particular ISP? Our site would stop working because we're relying on another site. We'd rather have all scripts residing on our server, so if our server's ok, so is the site.

Comment: Then you are better of using your own server.